# Is there a continuous surjective from $S^1$ to $[0,1]$?

Tags: general-topology

Is there a continuous surjective map from $S^1$ to $[0,1]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Start with a projection map and then modify it slightly.

Comment: More concretely, $f : S^1 = \{ e^{it} | 0 \le t < 2\pi \} \rightarrow [0,1]$ is given by $f(e^{it}) = |sin(t)|$

Comment: @user37116: If I had wanted to give a concrete map, I’d have done so. I can’t keep you from posting a complete solution as an answer, but I don’t appreciate having one appended as a comment to what was obviously intended **not** to be a complete solution.

Comment: And it would be nice if the downvoter would explain what’s wrong, though I’m not going to hold my breath.